# Convert resolution of geojson file from 1:10 to 1:110

Tags: geojson

After searching a while I finally found a [geojson file](https://gist.github.com/cmunns/76fb72646a68202e6bde) of the continents. But it is large file (even gzipped) and I do not need the high resolution (1:10). Can I somehow convert it smaller resolution (1:110)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/) has vector data of the Earth in different resolutions. The data comes as shapefiles, but saving to another file format is an easy task for almost all GIS software. Some of them (like QGIS) are free of charge.

Note that you can use the data in any scale you want, but low resolution shapes have less vertices.

You could try to simplify the geometry on your own with QGIS, GRASS or SAGA, but the result may be less satisfying than the Natural Earth dataset.

Comment: Looking at Natural Earth site, trying to understand, how can I get a shapefile for a continent, say Europe?

Comment: They have a world coastline, you have to cut it between Europe and Asia where you think it should be. A simple task with QGIS.